# Stripe Error: Transactions Won't Process Unless You're An Administrator

Tags: stripe

- Stripe transactions are giving  the following error for
  every role **except Administrator**:

"jquery.min.js:4 POST https://xxx.org/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fajax%2Frest 403"

- I have checked WordPress Access Control within CiviCRM and all roles have permissions to CiviCRM: access AJAX API

This is the information from the browser console:

- jquery.min.js:4
  **POST https://xxx.org/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fajax%2Frest - 403**
  send @ jquery.min.js:4
  ajax @ jquery.min.js:4
  CRM.api3 @crm.ajax.js?r=cA2tj:118
  (anonymous) @civicrmStripe.816e2274c63721669429369f97f76c08.js:259
  Promise.then (async)
  handleSubmitCard @civicrmStripe.816e2274c63721669429369f97f76c08.js:215
  submit @civicrmStripe.816e2274c63721669429369f97f76c08.js:689
  submitButtonClick @civicrmStripe.816e2274c63721669429369f97f76c08.js:485
  civicrmStripe: error: error
  civicrmStripe: Firing Event: crmBillingFormNotValid

CiviCRM version: 5.45.1.
Stripe: 6.6.3
SweetAlert: 1.5
Payment Shared: 1.2.1
WordPress: 5.9

I don't have any firewall plugins or WordPress roles plugin enabled.

Thank you in advance for any help!